# Creating a "swipe" animation when inflating a fragment

Tags: android, mobile-development

I'm trying to implement a "swipe" animation when opening a fragment.
Right now When the fragment is being shown from my MainActivity the fragment is being scrolled down (top-to-bottom), going over and covering the Activity.

What I'm trying to achieve is that instead of the fragment being rolled on top of the activity I want it to "push" the activity out of the way on its way down. Similar to how ViewPager animations work.

[Here is a rough sketch of what I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ys2QI.png)

From my limited experience with ViewPager, it can be used to "Swipe" between multiple activities **OR** multiple fragments, and you cannot mix & match.

Does anyone have an elegant solution on how to achieve this?
I really don't want to convert MainActivity into a fragment because there are tons and tons of code there.

Thanks in advance <3

Comment: This is can be achieved by [`CoordinatorLayout`](https://blog.mindorks.com/using-coordinator-layout-in-android) I guess.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need a BackDrop component.

[image: exaple]

for more information see the website below:
[material.io](https://material.io/components/backdrop#anatomy)

but there is no proper implementation in android you must implement this component by your own

you can use these website below to implement this component
[medium.com](https://medium.com/swlh/backdrop-in-android-material-design-e19fa97d4cf6)
[github.com](https://github.com/Semper-Viventem/Material-backdrop)